# how to set featured image in non-wordpress

Tags: php, html, facebook, seo, wordpress-featured-image

pasting wordpress url in fb status bring a featured image+some text
while when I put mine (core php site) url in fb status, it shows only text but picking no image while I have more than 10 images at that page
I googled a lot but almost all posts are wordpress related while I couldn't get how to make an image featured-image for a page on php/html (non-wordpress).
is there some html tag or attribute or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OpenGraph TAGs](http://ogp.me/), especially `og:image` for the image!

Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Comment: I have added `<meta property="og:image" content="images/alam.png" />` tag, it is showing other 3 images from that page but not `alam.png` mentioned in `og:image` tag

Comment: Use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Check the `Scraped URL` at the end and check if the `og:image` is already there. Facebook uses a cache system, maybe your page is not updated yet.

Comment: `scrap_url` is there `scrape_url=http%253A%252F%252Fdomain-name.com%252F&amp;remove_url=%2Fajax%2Fcomposerx%2Fattachment%2Fstatus%2F&amp;attachment_class=_4j&amp;av=100000613340718&amp;composerurihash=2"`

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Did you see if the `og:image` was there?

Comment: facebook `url debugger` do not show `og:image` while showing `og:title`, `og:type`, `og:url` and one additional which I have not put at my page that is `og:updated_time`

Comment: Could you share the link of your website here?

Comment: `og:image could not be downloaded or is too small` its minimum size is `200x200` while mine is `413x413`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89528/discussion-between-alamnaryab-and-berriel).

Answer (score 0):

While sharing you can upload image for the post manually.