# Setting up a featured image through javascript using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gtag.js

[how to set featured image in non-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554323/how-to-set-featured-image-in-non-wordpress)

I am wondering if I can dynamically set up a featured image through a Javascript tag. Is it possible to dynamically add a Google tag that runs only on certain pages and then run a script to put a meta tag with the value og:image inside the head and make the features image display on Facebook? Or do I somehow have to set it up manually in the backend somehow? I am thinking the web crawler may not detect it in time since it's added through javascript.

Comment: Nope. The various og:image scrapers won't execute your JavaScript.

Comment: You will have to add it in your backend, so according to your tags it would require some php code to dynamically set the tags.